# How to get user info by ID for SharePoint 2010 using REST?

Tags: 2010, rest, user-profile, user

This is for SharePoint 2010. I am using REST to query lists, but the "Created By" and "Modified By" columns are returning the user's numeric ID. I am wanting to get the user's fullname and email address, given their numeric ID.

I am using REST because the call is originating from a non-SharePoint app on a separate server.

If this was SP2013, the solution would be a simple `http://YOURSITE/_api/Web/GetUserById(userID)`

But being SP2010, this does not exist. I have spent a couple hours googlebinging and nothing has come near to being the answer.

Is this possible to do with SP2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could query the user information list for this. `http://your-site-name/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList(userid)` and get the properties you want using `$select`.

Or, you can just expand the created by and modified by fields by using:
`http://your-site-name/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ListName(itemId)?$expand=CreatedBy,ModifiedBy`

Update: Added itemId as a parameter to query list using item ID.

Comment: The first suggestion, `/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList(id)` works, and while it means doing separate calls to get the user info, it eases my pain for the day. The second suggestion, using `$expand=`, does not work, and only threw errors. I'm not sure exactly why, because $expand= is part of the REST API.

Comment: Weird. Tested in my 2010 site. Worked fine and it showed the created by and modified by fields with the user properties expanded.

Comment: Oops. My bad. Updated answer.