# Get user properties by specific Id - Not current Id

Tags: 2010, javascript, user-profile, user-profile-property

Is there a function call I can use to get user properties (login name, display name and\or title) from a specific user id, not the current user, but a user of my choice? I've tried a few variations out of sheer desperation with no luck.

```
var user = context.get_web().siteUsers().getById(userID);
```

or

```
var user = context.get_web().ensureUser(userID);
```

I'm not having any luck finding something. I can post the complete function I've built if need be. I'm getting .siteUser is not a function or .getById is not a function errors.

Answer (score 1):

**Using JSOM**:

Try this:

```
 var user = context.get_web().get_siteUsers().getById('userId');//Give the user id here
```

**Source**:

[How to get SharePoint User by User Id in JavaScript using JSOM](http://www.suhail.cloud/2015/06/how-to-get-sharepoint-user-by-user-id.html)

**Using REST**:

Try this:

```
http://your-site-name/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList(userId)
```

**Source**:

[How to get user info by ID for SharePoint 2010 using REST?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154711/how-to-get-user-info-by-id-for-sharepoint-2010-using-rest)

Answer (score 1):

Here is bunch of queries for specific user across all environment :

4) Get all properties of Specific User:

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|vardhaman@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premises:
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\username'

5) Get Specific UserProfile Property of Specific User:

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|vardhaman@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premises:
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='domain\username'

6) Get Multiple UserProfile Properties for Specific User:

Update (01/06/2016): Since the time I wrote this post, REST API batching has been implemented in SharePoint Online. As a result, we can make multiple REST requests to the GetUserProfilePropertiesFor function in a single REST call. This way, we can get Multiple custom/OOB UserProfile Properties for a Specific User without making multiple calls.

Here is my post on it:
SharePoint Online: Get UserProfile Properties with REST API Batching

List of User Properties (Use the GetPropertiesFor function for these):

AccountName
DirectReports
DisplayName
Email
ExtendedManagers
ExtendedReports
IsFollowed
LatestPost
Peers
PersonalUrl
PictureUrl"
Title
UserProfileProperties
UserUrl

Reference URL :

[SharePoint: Get User Profile Properties with REST API](https://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html?m=1)